# Routing Error uninitialized constant PdpwebController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know there are other post about this kind of error but i still can't seem to find the solution to my own project. Totally new to Rails. Thanks in advance.

my error:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant PdpwebController

Rails.root: C:/Users/x/Documents/pdpweb

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
```

Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom

```
Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
Path / Url      
Path Match
pwebs_path  GET /pwebs(.:format)    pwebs#index
POST    /pwebs(.:format)    pwebs#create
new_pweb_path   GET /pwebs/new(.:format)    pwebs#new
edit_pweb_path  GET /pwebs/:id/edit(.:format)   pwebs#edit
pweb_path   GET /pwebs/:id(.:format)    pwebs#show
PATCH   /pwebs/:id(.:format)    pwebs#update
PUT /pwebs/:id(.:format)    pwebs#update
DELETE  /pwebs/:id(.:format)    pwebs#destroy
root_path   GET /   pdpweb#home
```

My `route.rb`

```
Routing Error uninitialized constant PdpwebController

my pwebs_controller.rb
class pwebsController < ApplicationController
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is `pwebsController`

You can modify as:

```
class PwebsController < ApplicationController
end
```